# Android OpenGL ES Fatal signal crash

Tags: android, opengl-es

I attempting to render an exported model in .obj form (exported from blender). It is a sphere and my app crashes only on Nexus 5 phone. It is working on Andy emulator and other Android devices.

While debugging, I tried changing the value of the 'count' parameter, to see what would happen. My sphere has 960 faces (so I should draw 2880 to see the full model). However, if I put 1785 or more, it will crash. Using 1784 or less, it doesn't crash (but I only see a part of the model).

It crash on `GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 1784);`

```
private void draw()
{       

    mCubePositions.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mCubePositions);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);



    // Pass in the normal information
    mCubeNormals.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mNormalHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mCubeNormals);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mNormalHandle);

    // This multiplies the view matrix by the model matrix, and stores the result in the MVP matrix
    // (which currently contains model * view).
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);   

    // Pass in the modelview matrix.
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);                

    // This multiplies the modelview matrix by the projection matrix, and stores the result in the MVP matrix
    // (which now contains model * view * projection).        
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mTemporaryMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    System.arraycopy(mTemporaryMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, 16);

    // Pass in the combined matrix.
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);

    // Pass in the light position in eye space.        
    GLES20.glUniform3f(mLightPosHandle, mLightPosInEyeSpace[0], mLightPosInEyeSpace[1], mLightPosInEyeSpace[2]);

    // Draw the cube.
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 1784);                               
}
```

My OBJ reader

```
public static void readModel(Context context, int resId) {

    // read in all the lines and put in their respective arraylists of strings
    // reason I do this is to get a count of the faces to be used to initialize the
    // float arrays
    ArrayList<String> vertexes = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> vertexNormals = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> textures = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> faces = new ArrayList<String>();

    InputStream iStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resId);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(iStream);
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            // do not read in the leading v, vt or f
            if (line.startsWith("v ")) vertexes.add(line.substring(2));
            if (line.startsWith("vn ")) vertexNormals.add(line.substring(3));
            if (line.startsWith("vt ")) textures.add(line.substring(3));                
            if (line.startsWith("f ")) faces.add(line.substring(2));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // holding arrays for the vertices, texture coords and indexes

    float[] vCoords = new float[faces.size() *3*3];
    float[] vNCoords = new float[faces.size()*3*3];
    float[] vtCoords = new float[faces.size()*3*2];

    totalCaras = faces.size();
    int vertexIndex = 0;
    int faceIndex = 0;
    int textureIndex = 0;

    // for each face
    for (String i : faces) {
        // for each face component
        for (String j : i.split(" ")) {
            String[] faceComponent = j.split("//");

            String vertex = vertexes.get(Integer.parseInt(faceComponent[0]) - 1);
            String normal = vertexNormals.get(Integer.parseInt(faceComponent[1]) - 1);
            String vertexComp[] = vertex.split(" ");
            String normalComp[] = normal.split(" ");

            for (String v : vertexComp) {
                vCoords[vertexIndex++] = Float.parseFloat(v);
            }
             for (String n : normalComp) {
                vNCoords[faceIndex++] = Float.parseFloat(n);
            }


        }
    }


    mCubePositions = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vCoords.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    mCubePositions.put(vCoords).position(0);

    mCubeNormals = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vNCoords.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    mCubeNormals.put(vNCoords).position(0);


}
```

The only trace that logcat shows:

```
06-10 09:08:32.016: D/OpenGLRenderer(6041): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
06-10 09:08:32.027: D/Atlas(6041): Validating map...
06-10 09:08:32.074: I/Adreno-EGL(6041): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 01/14/15, ab0075f, Id3510ff6dc
06-10 09:08:32.075: I/OpenGLRenderer(6041): Initialized EGL, version 1.4

06-10 09:05:05.724: D/OpenGLRenderer(5242): Enabling debug mode 0
06-10 09:05:05.878: A/libc(5242): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x74615000 in tid 5279 (GLThread 13643)
```

Comment: what is `mCubePositions`?

Comment: The float buffer that contains the vertex coordinates

Comment: Yes, but it's your code, perhaps the error is in there? For example, you haven't allocated enough storage in your object?

Comment: I added the obj reader to the question, but I think that I allocated enough storage, since it works on other devices which are less powerful